# Remove delimiter using C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, delimiter

I Have a string as follows:

```
{a{b,c}d}
```

if i give 1, the string must be displayed as:

```
{a d}
```

the content within inner braces should be removed along with the braces.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: "if i give 1". Give 1 to what? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: is the string alway build like this ? {*{*,*}*}

Comment: How do you handle multiple level nestings?

Comment: if pair of braces to be removed is 1, then i have to remove the inner braces along with its content

Comment: not always... it can be,
{a{b{c,d,e}f}g}h

Answer (score 5):

To extract the inner grouping of {} use the following regular expression:

```
string extract = Regex.Replace(source, "\{\w(\{\w,\w\})\w\}", "$1");
```

Actually, if you want to remove the comma....

```
string extract = Regex.Replace(source, "\{\w\{(\w),(\w)\}\w\}", "{$1 $2}");
```

To extract the outer without the inner grouping:

```
string extract = Regex.Replace(source, "(\{\w)\{\w,\w\}(\w\})", "$1 $2");
```

if in your example a, b, c, d are not literally single characters, that is groups of letters or even spaces, etc replace **\w** with **\w+** or even **.***

based on your comment on nesting....

```
string extract = Regex.Replace(source, "(\{\w)\{.*\}(\w\})\w*", "$1 $2");
```

Comment: darn right... a regex is really worth more here... why didn't i think that way... definetly +1 from me!

Comment: Just replaced the \s to \w... sorry \s is whitespace, haven't had my coffee yet... (\w) is digit, underscore or character. Oh and thanks!

Comment: My apologies, the { } need to be escaped via \. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 1):

### go the regex-way above... it's really more beautiful!

---

you could do it by hand... i've written something for paranthesis in an example a few years ago... have to look for it a sec...:

```
     string def = "1+2*(3/(4+5))*2";
     int pcnt = 0, start = -1, end = -1;
     bool subEx = false;
     if(def.Contains("(") || def.Contains(")"))
        for(int i = 0; i < def.Length; i++) {
           if(def[i] == '(') {
              pcnt++;
              if(!subEx)
                 start = i;
           } else if(def[i] == ')')
              pcnt--;
           if(pcnt < 0)
              throw new Exception("negative paranthesis count...");
           if(pcnt != 0)
              subEx = true;
           if(subEx && pcnt == 0 && end == -1)
              end = i;
        }
     if(pcnt != 0) {
        throw new Exception("paranthesis doesn't match...");
     }
     if(subEx) {
        string firstPart = def.Substring(0, start);
        string innerPart = def.Substring(start + 1, end - (start + 1));
        string secondPart = def.Substring(end + 1);
        Console.WriteLine(firstPart);
        Console.WriteLine(innerPart);
        Console.WriteLine(secondPart);
     }
```

writes:

```
1+2*
3/(4+5)
*2
```

Comment: Thank u. But I have to remove the content within the braces too.

Answer (score 0):

namespace Delimiter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string src = "a{b{c{d,e}f}g}h";
            int occurenceCount = 0;
            foreach (char ch in src)
            {
                if(ch == '{')
                {
                    occurenceCount++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a no. to remove block: ");
            int givenValue = 0;
            CheckValid(out givenValue);

```
        int removeCount = occurenceCount + 1 - givenValue;
        occurenceCount = 0;
        int startPos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < src.Length; i++)
        {
            if (src[i] == '{')
            {
                occurenceCount++;
            }   
            if(occurenceCount == removeCount)
            {
                startPos = i;
                break;
                //i value { of to be removed block
            }
        }
        int endPos = src.IndexOf('}', startPos);
        src = src.Remove(startPos,endPos);

        //index of }
        Console.WriteLine("after reved vale:" + src);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void CheckValid(out int givenValue)
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out givenValue))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid no. to remove block: ");
            CheckValid(out givenValue);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: but the problem here is in the following line:
 src = src.Remove(startPos,endPos);
            im not getting exact things removed.